# How to access items of a .net collection using jquery in webforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, webforms

Within an asp webform project I am making a call to a web service that returns a result collection as follows.

Pseudo code return of collection

```
content (items are key value pair) 
 ID, 001
 Title , My Book
 DateCreated , 10/10/2011
 Author, JSmith
```

What I would like to do is on the initial return only display the title of the book in a data repeater and then once the user clicks on a detail display the remaining fields in a separate pane div container of the form. I've done this in the past with generic lists in Silverlight and in MVC however in this project I cannot use either.

In conducting some research I have seen where people are using json to make similar calls. However I debugged with fiddler and I can see that entire collection is being returned to the UI  so it seems  I should be able to go directly at the collection vs making a new call back to the server? Within the UI I am not using asp:net controls but standard html to render the data in the data in the UI.

Example

```
<div class="resultcontainer">
                    <span class="labeltitle-small">Book Title</span><br />
                    <%= BookResults[0].Title %>
                </div>
```

I'm able to query and return the results however where I am stuck is the best approach to display what I'll refer to as secondary data for the associated record.

I'd really appreciate any suggestions on how (from the client) to only show a view value of the collection and then once a record is selected have the other values displayed to the user.

Thank you

Comment: You have to make a call back to the server. How could code running in my web browser on my computer have direct access to your server's data structure?

Comment: @Pointy That is what is confusing me. When the result is returned and bound to the uI are you saying that only the properties explicitly defined in the UI persist? Is there no in memory collection pushed into the client that contains the other properties? With MVC and MVVM this was the case I could bind to the view and then access the properties as needed. I am guessing this is not the case with webforms?  Based upon what you are saying the collection is destroyed once the UI renders it out so that the values are no longer accessible from the client without making a trip back to the server?

Comment: No, everything that gets to the client is contained in the HTTP response under your explicit control.  The browser environment has absolutely no awareness of server-side state via any other means. If there's something the page needs that wasn't included when it was originally fetched, then yes the client must make another request to the server.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, perhaps a bit obvious, but have you considered a little bit of AJAX, using `jQuery.ajax`? You could attach an onclick even handler to the div and load the data in the appropriate part of the page when the user selects a particular book.

You can return a partial view from the controller. The resulting HTML can be displayed  in a div using something along the lines of `$("#detailDiv").html(partialView)`.

Comment: Thanks Pieter, Your solution is accurate but also seems to be dependent upon an MVC pattern approach. Which puts the dependency of creating a controller, view and data context to push the partial view into the webform which is a little more that I want to do for this piece of the project.